# TS error using css "position" when passing style object to Emotion's css prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion, css-in-js

I have a React component roughly with this structure:

```
    // This does not work.
    const style = {
       position: 'absolute'
       // ...other css props
    }
    
    const Component = () => {
       return <div css={style}/>
    }
```

That structure seems to work for all other css props but if I include the `position` prop in the object, I get the following TypeScript errors:

`Type '{ //... }' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<Theme>'`

`Type '{ //... }'is not assignable to type 'undefined'.  TS2322`

Passing the position prop directly inline to the css prop works just fine:

```
   // This works.
   const style = {           
      // ...other css props
   }
    
   const Component = () => {
      return <div css={{ position: 'absolute', ...style }}/>
   }
```

Any idea of why I can´t include the position prop in the style object?

Comment: Hey, I would like to recommend you to have a look at the props. You are assigning value to css prop where as i feel it should be style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710747/type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-inherit-initial-unset-fixe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using plan object value as `css` prop value for emotion directly.
Only direct input of `css` style object into `css` prop would work with emotion.

Please check https://emotion.sh/docs/object-styles.

To use `css` style object, you need to define it as emotion's Style Object using `css`.

```js
const style= css({
  position: 'absolute',
  ...otherStyles
})
```

Comment: Oh, that seems to do it. Weird, I had always been using plain objects with no issue and only noticed once I had to use the position prop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful if you show the other attributes you're passing in the styles object. Post the code for the `div` component and the output of log errors if possible.

Another question, but I don't think this was the main issue: I think it might be a good practice if you use your `div` component in camelCase syntax, like `DivComponent`, for example.  To avoid confusing it with the `div` html tag.

Comment: Regarding initial part its very well indicated in the question that when the value is assigned with a general value it works e.g color: 'green' but does not work when another property is added for example position: 'absolute'. One more thing regarding 'DivComponent' there is no mentioning of such component in the original question. What's build the assumption regarding 'DivComponent'.

Comment: Oh, it's a regular div, I actually don't like the styled component syntax to be honest, it feels a bit inflexible to me.